# DefaultHttpClient hangs on execute() method in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, androidhttpclient, android-5.1.1-lollipop

In one of our old project we are using `DefaultHttpClient` for `networking`. its working fine below `lollipop` devices but in `lollipop` get request hangs `execute` method call.
We are creating `HttpClient` like this.

```
public static MyHttpClient createHttpClient(Context ctx) {    
        try {
            if(mgr == null){            
                SSLSocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();        
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);        

                httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();        
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);        
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT); 
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();   
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));        
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));        

                mgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry);
            }
            return new MyHttpClient(mgr, httpParameters);    
        } catch (Exception e) {        
            return new MyHttpClient(ctx);    
        }
    }
```

We are also setting timeouts. Any idea why its freezing there and how we can fix that?

**Edit:** one more thing that i have missed. It only happens when we hit same URL 3rd time. First two times it works fine.

Comment: whats the value for `HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT`

Comment: @petey I have replaced HOST_REACH_TIMEOUT  with value.

Comment: 2min is pretty high,  try 15000?

Comment: I have tried with 1 min same result. one more thing that i have missed. It only happens when we hit same URL 3rd time. First two times it works fine.

Comment: Just a thought. Do you call `releaseConnection()` after you're done with the connection?

Comment: Instantiate every time a new mgr.

Comment: I am not using releaseConnection. I have tried response.getEntity().consumeContent();

Comment: @greenapps "Instantiate every time a new mgr" solved the problem but don't know if team will approve this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate every time a new mgr.